# Books recommendation on Graph Theory (Beginner level)

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, book-recommendation

What are some of the best books on graph theory, particularly for the beginners. 
Thank you.

Comment: http://diestel-graph-theory.com/index.html

Comment: Brualdi is popular. I got a used copy for like 2USD on eBay in high school and it wound up being the text used in an undergrad graph theory and combinatorics course.

Comment: Diestel is hardly a beginner's book.

Answer (score 3):

I quess [*Graph Theory by F.Harary*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201410338) is the best one. There are a lot of properties of different graphs. And at the end of all paragraphs, you could check yourself and try to solve some problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm partial to Doug West. It's very thorough, friendly, and well written. You'll get the basics- trees, connectivity, independent sets, matchings, flows, and colorings. West also covers advanced topics like Ramsey Theory, spectral graph theory, random graphs and matroids. He also has an appendix on NP-Completeness proofs, which are relevant to computer scientists. I would consider West to be a more classical graph theory text.

I haven't used Bondy-Murty, but I've heard good things about it.

Diestel is a solid book, but it is not a beginner level book. Diestel does cover a lot of material that West doesn't, but it's covered at a more mathematically mature manner. Diestel is a text that covers topics you should see if you are attending graph theory conferences. It covers more modern graph theory.

If you are looking for a brief introduction, Nick Loehr's Bijective Combinatorics text has a solid chapter on graph counting. One could teach the graph theory unit in an undergraduate Applied Combinatorics course from this one chapter in Loehr.

I would discourage you from using Alan Tucker's Applied Combinatorics text. It's good for problems but has terrible exposition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the book by  *[R.B.J.T. Allenby, Alan Slomson, How to Count An Introduction to Combinatorics](https://www.crcpress.com/How-to-Count-An-Introduction-to-Combinatorics-Second-Edition/Allenby-Slomson/9781420082609)*. It is rather a (Probably the best) book for rudimentary combinatorics, but here in the chapter $9$, Detailed introduction to Graphs are given. After studying these, you can study higher standard books on this topic. but this is hard to find. So, [*Edgar G. Goodaire and Michael M. Parmenter. Discrete Mathematics with Graph Theory*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131679953)  is a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I thought [A First Course in Graph Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486483681) by Gary Chartrand and Ping Zhang was an excellent, soft introduction to graph theory when I first learned it in undergrad. Not to mention the actual textbook is very cheap!